# undefined reference to '<function>'

Tags: c, undefined-reference, jam

I am working on a large piece of code. When I compile the code base using jam command, I get a lot of errors saying undefined reference to 'some_function' in a newly added header file in the code base. This header file includes all other relevant header files. Do I need to make changes to the jam file before I can compile the code base?

**bundlemgr_distrib_im.c:**

```
#include "bundlemgr_distrib_config.h"
.
.
function{
.
.
retcode = bmd_cfg_init_active(bmd_im_evh);
.
.
}
```

**bundlemgr_distrib_config.h:**

```
cerrno bmd_cfg_init_active(event_mgr_p evh); //declaration
```

**bundlemgr_distrib_config.c**

```
#include "bundlemgr_distrib_config.h"
.
.
cerrno bmd_cfg_init_active(event_mgr_p evh)
{
//definition
}
```

**Build log:**

```
...failed Link bundle/bundlemgr/test/obj-x86/bm_ut_distrib_attr ...
...skipped <installed!rp>bm_ut_distrib_attr for lack of <bundle!bundlemgr!test!obj-x86>bm_ut_distrib_attr...
.
.
bugfix/./bundle/bundlemgr/distrib/src/bundlemgr_distrib_im.c:269: undefined reference to `bmd_cfg_init_active'
```

*Another error:*

**bundlemgr_distrib_acc_private.h** (newly added file)

```
#include "bundlemgr_distrib_db_api.h"
#include "bundlemgr_distrib_db_private.h"
.
.
function{
.
.
rc = bmd_db_bdl_change_ifh(entry, ifhandle);
.
.
}
```

**bundlemgr_distrib_db_private.h**

```
cerrno bmd_db_bdl_change_ifh(bmd_db_bdl_h_type  entry,
                          ifhtype            ifhandle); //declaration
```

**bundlemgr_distrib_db_api.c**

```
#include "bundlemgr_distrib_db_private.h"
.
.
cerrno  
bmd_db_bdl_change_ifh (bmd_db_bdl_type *entry,                                                                                                                                                                                          
                    ifhtype          ifhandle)
{
//definition
}
```

**Build log:**

```
...failed Link bundle/bundlemgr/test/obj-x86/bm_ut_distrib_attr ...
...skipped <installed!rp>bm_ut_distrib_attr for lack of <bundle!bundlemgr!test!obj-x86>bm_ut_distrib_attr...
Link bundle/bundlemgr/test/obj-x86/bm_ut_distrib_mbr_info
bundle/bundlemgr/test/obj-x86/bundlemgr_distrib_test_errdis_owner.o: In function `bmd_acc_bdl_set_ifhandle':
/nobackup/pzambad/ci-521-bugfix/./bundle/bundlemgr/distrib/src/bundlemgr_distrib_acc_private.h:3618: undefined reference to `bmd_db_bdl_change_ifh'
```

Comment: Plyush, are the errors generated by the compiler, or the linker?

Comment: These are link errors..

Comment: @Plyush, Being linker errors, they are not associated with a header file.  Rather, the errors are indicating that there is insufficient code to resolve the symbols listed.  Perhaps there is a library that needs to be used to resolve the symbols, (or perhaps multiple .c files must be compiled and linked together to resolve the symbols)?  You might consider posting a few of the linker errors with you question; that might help identify the missing element.

Comment: @Mahonri: Added some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the linker where to find the library files that go with those headers. There will often be a /lib directory containing the required libraries. With the [Gnu toolchain](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html#SEC3) use `-l` for including a specific library or `-L` for adding a library path.